# How can I determine used and free space in an e-mail folder?

Tags: imap, jakarta-mail, pop3

I haven't found any method in JavaMail API do do such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [QuotaAwareStore](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/QuotaAwareStore.html) interface in JavaMail.  IMAP Store objects will implement this interface, but not all IMAP servers implement the IMAP extension needed to make it work.  Plus, you'll want to read [RFC 2087](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2087.txt) to understand how quotas work.  You might need documentation for your mail server to see how (and if) it implements quotas.

If you're using POP3, you can use the [POP3Folder.getSize() method](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Folder.html#getSize%28%29) to see how much space is used by the folder, but there's no way to find out how much free space you have or how much you're allowed to use.